# .net lambda expression casting

Tags: .net, lambda, expression

maybe what I'm trying to achieve is a non-sense, but I think it should work.
I have an expression

```
Expression<Func<Model.Document, bool>> expr1 = d => //something
```

I nedd to cast this Expression in a

```
Expression<Func<Model.Invoice, bool>
```

where Model.Invoice inherits from Model.Document

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really to do with lambda expressions - it's to do with expression trees and `Expression<TDelegate>` in particular. `Expression<TDelegate>` is invariant in T - and even if it weren't, the relationship between `Func<Model.Document, bool>` and `Func<Model.Invoice, bool>` wouldn't be appropriate for covariance, unless I'm mistaken (which is quite possible).

I suspect you'll need to break up the `Expression<T>` and recreate it, which may not be terribly simple... alternatively you could add a wrapper layer *around* the existing `Expression<T>`, which would be semi-equivalent to saying:

```
 Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> = invoice => (d => ...)(invoice);
```

Comment: I like the wrapper idea, but I didn't get how it should work. I have Expression<Func<Document, bool>> expr1 = d => true; and I need to obtain Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> expr2; How can I wrap expr1?

Comment: @themarcuz: You'll need to investigate the Expression API - basically work out how to call one expression from another. I can't think of the details off the top of my head, but I'd expect it to be possible...